# Passing parameter(s) to function(s) withing different project files in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++-2010

I just am getting confused about passing the parameter to function in C++ over different projects.

I have two different solutions, of which one is a DLL project and another is Console project. Within the first project I have a piece of code as follows:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) FormatLog
{
public:
    void __cdecl ParseFormat(LPCWSTR);
};
```

The rest of codes are not important herein, whereas in the second project I have the header file consisting of the following code:

```
class FormatImpl
{
public:
    typedef void (__cdecl * FORMAT) (LPCWSTR);
    HINSTANCE hModule;
    FORMAT Format;
    FormatImpl()
    {
        hModule = LoadLibrary(L"FormatLog.dll");
        if (hModule != NULL)
        {
            Format = (FORMAT) GetProcAddress(hModule, "?ParseFormat@FormatLog@@XXXXXXXX@X");
        }
    }
    ~FormatImpl()
    {
        if (hModule != NULL)
        {
            FreeLibrary(hModule);
        }
    }
};
```

When I was calling this from the main function using the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FormatImpl format;
    format.Format(L"%t %m %i %l");
    return 0;
}
```

the parameter became invalid in function `void __cdecl ParseFormat(LPCWSTR format);` as `<Bad Ptr>` while inspecting through the Visual Studio 2010.

My question is, if I use `GetProcAddress` or `LoadLibrary` to call a .dll file invoking any method, shouldn't I thereby be legitimate to pass any parameter apart from int, double, long or so on to the requested method?

Comment: Shouldn't the function pointer be declared like `typedef void (__cdecl * FORMAT) (LPCWSTR,...);`?

Comment: Are you asking me to include `vadefs.h` to use `va_start` and `va_end`, instead?

Comment: Well such like a format function might require this, yes. But I'm talking about the function pointer signature primarily. Please edit a bit, and provide a more concise example, how is that function declared in the DLL for instance?

Comment: Well, I tried this before as well, but it still gave me no proper solution to hold the actual parameter throughout the projects.

Comment: Well the function signature of the .dll file is `void __cdecl ParseFormat(LPCWSTR);` [or `void __cdecl ParseFormat(LPCWSTR log, ...);` doesn't make sense in such regard]. May this information be too tiny but my problem doesn't consider the signature rather the parameter that I wanted to pass through.

Comment: I have completely no clue, what you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry for that, but I have no extra point to clarify herewith. Did you go through the problem carefully I furnished here?

Comment: _"shouldn't I thereby be legitimate to pass any parameter apart from int, double, long or so on to the requested method?"_ Of course you should be able to put any parameter along the types declared in the function pointers signature. Does this actually help?

Comment: In accordance with the function pointers signature neither `const char *` nor the `const wchar_t *` be passed to work with. I just wanted to load the DLL file using the `LoadLibrary` and reference the function using `GetProcAddress`. But unluckily the signature couldn't give me a wise space to implement my logic thereby. Anyways, thanks for your efforts on giving a right solution therefore.

Comment: As written, it's not clear where the variable `Format` is declared, or that `GetProcAddress()` is being called before you try to call the DLL function.  Does it work if you assign the results of GetProcAddress to a local variable and try to call it from that?  eg: `main() { FORMAT f = GetProcAddress(...); f(L"%t %m %i %l"); return 0; }`

Comment: Well, I'd recommend you improve your question with a [MCVE](yhttp://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that any one can reproduce it having VS2010 at hand (I don't have unfortunately).

Comment: I just have edited and purified the question, and as I am using VS2010 to debug my code, it doesn't perform any other advantages in finding the solution thereby.

Comment: `FreeLibrary(hModule);` Shouldn't that go to the destructor rather being called from construction code??

Comment: Well sure it should, if you surely want me to do so...

Comment: Since `ParseFormat` is a non-static member of `FormatLog`, aren't you missing an `FormatLog* instance` argument in the function signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a major problem in your code: `ParseFormat` is **not** a function taking a LPWSTR and returning void but an instance method of class `FormatLog`. The difference is that for an instance method, you have a hidden `this` parameter.

If you have control on first project, the simplest way IMHO is to just use a static method to get rid of the hidden parameter:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) FormatLog
{
public:
    static void __cdecl ParseFormat(LPCWSTR);
};
```

If you have no control on first project, the correct type for `FORMAT` would be a pointer to member. Unfortunately I could never find a way to convert the result of `GetProcAddress` to a pointer to member. Hopefully, it is known that that you can simply get the address of the member function and call it directly, **provided you add the hidden `this` as first parameter**. The code would become:

```
class FormatImpl
{
public:
    typedef void (__cdecl *FORMAT) (FormatLog *l, LPCWSTR);
    HINSTANCE hModule;
    FORMAT Format;
    FormatImpl()
    {
        hModule = LoadLibrary(L"FormatLog.dll");
        if (hModule != NULL)
        {
            Format = (FORMAT) (void *) GetProcAddress(hModule,
                "?ParseFormat@FormatLog@@QAAXPB_W@Z");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

(after getting the mangled name in `FormatLog.exp`) and you will use it like that:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FormatImpl format;
    FormatLog l;
    format.Format(&l, L"%t %m %i %l");
    return 0;
}
```

Anyway, I generally think that the mangled names should be an implementation detail and I only export `extern "C"` functions from a DLL if I later want to import them manually through `GetProcAddress`.

So my advice would be to add in first project:

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl doParseFormat(LPWSTR str) {
        static FormatLog flog;

        flog.ParseFormat(str);
    }
}
```

Now you can simply write:

```
Format = (FORMAT) GetProcAddress(hModule, "doParseFormat");
```

which I personnaly find more clean, and you can use it easily.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable and to-the-point answer. It really helped me to do what I wanted to. But the first option `format.Format(&l, L"%t %m %i %l");` failed because it referenced the passed parameter as null string; i.e. `""` apart from `<Bad Ptr>`. But thanks for the `__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl doParseFormat(LPCWSTR);` signature.